# Python - @property vs func()

Tags: python, function, properties

It had always been my dream to use `someclass.func` instead of `someclass.func()`. I read about the `@decorators`. And now I ask:

Which way is better?

### Way 1

```
class Main(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.func()

    def func(self):

        print 'hi'
```

or...

### Way 2

```
class Main(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.func

    @property
    def func(self):

        print 'hi'
```

---

### EDIT

Here is the code:
http://randomgalaxy.com/stackoverflow/python-property-vs-func/term.py

Comment: Depends on what you want func() to later be used for.

Comment: This is a question of what API you want to present, which depends entirely on your application and needs. Without context, this is unanswerable.

Comment: @ChristianTernus, I am writing a GUI application using wxPython. This function will refresh styling in my StyledTextCtrl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `func` really *prints* values, then no, making it a property is not the right thing to do. Properties are—as the name suggest—values that are attached to the object. As such, a function with the `@property` decorator should *only* return a value and have otherwise no side-effects.

Comment: So it's a bad idea to do something else there? I mean in my script function changes my vars and calls another functions

Comment: Yes, that’s a bad idea. The object *state* shouldn’t change from simply accessing the property and reading its value. For example accessing `x.func` multiple times in a short time should make no problem and it being a property suggests that this is absolutely fine. If that function actually *does* something to the object, then keep it a method.

Comment: I want to disagree a little bit, you can use `@property` to implement a memmoized pattern and do some caching.  It's not a public state change, but it's still a state change.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: after reading your actual code DEFINITELY Way 1

Most likely: Way 1

BUT it depends on what you're actually trying to do.  This case you presented is way oversimplified.

Using the @property decorator is in my experience either a way to protect a class member (only allowing reads), A way to do some bookkeeping when a variable is set/read, or a way to provide access to a member-like function (ie, just returns a value you request even if it requires some extra computation to get that value). I personally like to use it for lazy evaluation

Answer (score 1):

Properties should be **values**. Not functions.
Example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.__a = a
        self.__b = b

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.__a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.__b
```

In this example, values are **private** and you can't change them.

> So it's a bad idea to do something else there? I mean in my script function changes my vars and calls another functions –  Vik2015 45 secs ago

It's very bad style. You're not in ruby :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will accept @poke answer as he explained a bit better :)

Comment: @user2892431 Does ruby have some tactic to handle this case where it is not bad style?